# Convert EXE file to something like os

Tags: c#

Hi is it possible to convert a program written in C# to Operating System or just run it and use it like Windows. I mean boot C# program like Windows.
I need something like Windows but Windows size is 3 Gigabyte I need Windows with 200 megabyte to run on a small mother board that I created.

Comment: That's not the way you should ask for that. And normally windows is about 15 Gb+.

Comment: Wtf...Really? The short answer is NO, you can't

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes - apart from the odd capitalization and phrasing its a valid technical question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you googled ".net Operating System" you would find the COSMOS project which allows you to write an operating system in .net.

https://github.com/CosmosOS/Cosmos/wiki/Develop-Your-Own-Operating-System-in-C%23-or-VB.NET

Comment: thanks but i use it and a lot of error happened because cosmos need to write plug for everything that you are using at there for example mouse need a lot of code for moving and i couldn't use any method Available in vs. @PhillipH

Comment: I think the point about COSMOS is that it allows you to write your own OS - that means you have to write your own OS - mouse, keyboard, command processor, GUI .. everything is yours. I guess you don't really want to run a C# application as an OS but have a cut down OS to run your C# within.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Windows 10 IoT Core](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot). It's designed to run on small motherboards like a Raspberry Pi and might give you what you're looking for.

Comment: The OP specifically asked to be able to run C# programs as an operating system.

Comment: @PhillipH He also said that he needed something like Windows but smaller, so I took a shot at answering the real problem rather than the specific question. If he wants to run a C# UWP program on his custom board, Windows IoT comes with that standard without the need to rebuild or customize anything.